# Kernel dies whenever using pandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I keep trying to add this CSV file into my notebook using pandas, but whenever i do so, i immediately get told that my kernel has died. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhs50.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How large is your CSV file? Check that you arent running out of ram.

Comment: i checked and i'm on 6gb out of 8. i've tried to do it again but i get the same result. The CSV file is 155 bytes